# $wpdb->get_results is EMPTY in one email template, while fine in other

Tags: wordpress

I just created account (newbie here pls be patient) becouse i starting to pull my hair out.

I got a very simple query in email-order-items.php

```
$posts_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'WooCommerceEventsOrderID' AND meta_value = '$order->id'");
print_r($posts_data);
```

This work perfectly on email sent to customer but doesn't work with admin email.
Customer email shows result, admin email is always an ampy array.

Both emails use the same part of code so why is that?
What's weird - when i re-send email from back office (Order actions / Resend new order notification) than email template gets correct array.

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCfCp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Has `$wpdb` been instantiated yet in that code/function with `global $wpdb;` before you're calling it?

Comment: Yes it has, sorry I didn’t mention that in description